# react native plugin for carousel together with native base tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am new in react-native.

Currently I am using RN 0.59,

I am using carousel *https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel*
then I have tabs using native base. *https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref*

This works fine on IOS but on android the swiping on the carousel doesn't work.
So, I did a workaround for, I setup a state that will lock the tabs once the Component was press in.

On my page

```
<Carousel
 ...
 ...
 renderItem={(data, key) => {
    return (
        <View ...>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
               ...
               delayPressIn={0} 
               onPressIn={() => toggleTabLocked() } // this set to true or false the state
               >
               ...
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    );
}}>
```

on my tab component

```
<Tabs
    ...
    ...
    locked={tabLocked} // state from reducer
>
    ....
</Tabs>
```

This is a work around on my end.
But the issue issue is, it is not that smooth in terms on transition and swiping.

Is there any workaround or suggestion for the plugin I am using?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I have the same issue, It's been a year and a half and I couldn't find any solution, I will try to use your workaround(thanks) because I didn't find anything yet...I m also new to react and I'm using currently react 0.63 :(